# Highlight DropdownMenuItem using the touch event of the first letters like websites

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, user-interface

```
final List<String> dropdownItems = [
  'Harris',
  'Marcus',
  'Dom',
  'Darnry',
  'Honarat',
];
```

I should be able to open the drop-down menu, press M to highlight the first menu item starting with M in this case Marcus, and hit enter to select it. I'm not sure if this is something feasible.